# Works without memset when I'm from another function in C

Tags: c

When I'm from the `success()` function I don't need to set things back to `0` but when I'm looping the sequence inside the same function I have to set back the memory of psswrd to 0 at its size using `memset(psswrd,0,sizeof(psswrd));` so what's the difference that it works without memset when I'm from another function?

---

After fellow users have commented on my code (Thanks for critizing, I learned from it), I revised it using new loop and the question of mine is now invinsible through this code, so a new question of mine, is why when I'm from another function like `success()` for example, I don't need to set back it's memory to `0`? Is it automatically set back to its default initialization because of the declarations?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>

success(){
    clrscr();
    printf("Press Any Key to Go Back and Login ");
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int cnt;
void login(){
    char    ch,
    mypass[]="thepass",
    psswrd[256]={0};
    do{
        cnt=NULL;
        memset(psswrd,0,sizeof(psswrd));
        clrscr();
        printf("Enter Password: ");
        do{
            ch=getch();
            if( isprint(ch) ){
                psswrd[ cnt++ ] = ch;
                printf("%c", ch);
                }
            else
            if(ch==8 && cnt){
                psswrd[ cnt-- ] = '\0';
                printf("%s", "\b \b");
                }
            }
        while(ch!=13);
        }
    while(strcmp(psswrd,mypass));
    }

void main(){
    do{
        login();
        success();
    }
    while(!success());
    }
```

Comment: I stopped reading after I hit "goto". There is a time and place for "goto" but this is not one.

Comment: You're not initializing `cnt` before you use it.

Comment: ...that and a few other issues.

Comment: Haha! Thanks for critizing, @CharlieBurns you made answer my own question... After I revised my loops and initialization, I already understood it, but to clarify it, I will correct the question :)

Comment: Haha! Thanks for critizing, @ChrisOlsen you made answer my own question... After I revised my loops and initialization, I already understood it, but to clarify it, I will correct the question :)

Comment: Is there anymore I could do to improve it?

Comment: @Daniel glad you found an answer.  For feedback on your code, you could try posting over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have learned from revising my code the initialization itself sets back the variable to `0`
which happens at this line:

```
char    ch, mypass[]="thepass", psswrd[256]={0};
```

while in looping my code, the loop doesn't reach the initialization, also, the declarations shouldn't be inside the loop, cause the variables will also be used by `while()` function

The solution is to set back its memory back to `0` using `memset()` function.

Answer (score 1):

`psswrd` is never empty. It's an array and always has the same size. In your case, it's always 8 characters big (the 7 you specified plus the automatically inserted `\0` char at the end.)

To "empty" a string means setting its length to zero. In C, the convention is that a string is considered to end at the first occurrence of `\0`. So in order to set the length to zero, you simply set the first element of the character array to 0. You do not need to memset() the whole thing:

```
psswrd[0] = 0;
```

When `cnt` is 0 (it's an `int`, so `NULL` is just confusing), then the above is what happens and the string is considered to be of zero length and thus empty.